# The Class inside Class variable (python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, class

```
class FirstClass(object):

  def __init__(root):
    root.name = "First Name"

      class SecondClass(object):
          def __init__(self):
              self.name = root.name
          def myFuction(self):
              return self.name 
print FirstClass.SecondClass.myFuction
```

my expect result should be "First Name".
But I can't get the variable from first class.
How should I do?

Comment: Fix your indentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't; inner classes are a distinct namespace, even though they are an attribute of the outer class's namespace. You will need to pass an instance of the outer class to the inner class or its method if you want to access any of its attributes.

Comment: Does it have another way to make Class1.Class2.Function
(Class 2 should get variable from Class1 and Function belong Class2) Thanks

Comment: Again: Distinct namespaces. No.